# Remove Add-in in Powerpoint with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-addins

I have a VBA Add-in in PowerPoint that is updated occassionally. I wrote a code in VBA where every Monday there is a check wether a newer version of the Add-in exists. And if it does, PowerPoint automatically updates the Add-In. So far, I have this accomplished:

- Deactivate the old Add-In in PowerPoint
- Delete the old Add-in in Microsoft's Add-In folder
- Copy the new Add-In to Microsoft's Add-In folder
- Activate the new Add-in in PowerPoint

However, I can't seem to find the right command to delete the old Add-in in PowerPoint. The old Add-in is still in PowerPoint's available Add-ins, and PowerPoint also lists it under the inactive Application Add-ins.

Here's part of the Code that first deactivates the Add-in, and then tries to remove it from PowerPoint.

```
Dim oAddin As AddIn
For Each oAddin In Application.AddIns
   If Left(oAddin.name, 16) = "PPT ACO Add-in V" Then
       oAddin.Loaded = msoFalse
       Kill (oAddin) '<-- these is the line of Code that doesn't execute
   End if
Next oAddin
```

The program would work, but after some time I'd have a bunch of inactive Add-ins laying around in PowerPoint which will be very confusing to users.

Thank you so much for your help guys.

Tommy

Comment: Kill (oAddin) isn't going to work (in will probably just throw errors; do you have On Error Resume Next set and no error handler?)   After restarting PPT do the old add-ins still get listed in Inactive Addins?  Kill (xx) expects a fully pathed filename and will delete the file; try Kill (oAddin.Fullname) instead. But first use oAddin.Registered = msoFalse

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, Kill did produce an error, so I did use On Error Resume next to continue the subroutine. The new Add-in is being loaded, and the old one put on the inactive list. However, after a restart of PowerPoint, the new Add-in has disappeared in PowerPoint, and the old one is loaded again. I've tried the following commans, but none of them worked: Kill oAddin.FullName, Kill (oAddin.Path), oAddin.AutoLoad = msoFalse, oAddin.Application.Visible = msoFalse, oAddin.Registered = msoFalse, oAddin.Application.Visible = msoFalse, Kill oAddin, Kill (oAddin)

Comment: What is weird is that I was previously able to delete the old Add'in from Microsoft's default Add-in folder. Now that part of the code doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

very late answer, but since I passed by and I spent myself quite sometime on this issue, instead of

```
kill (oAddin)
```

you need

```
kill oAddin.fullname
```

although you should also remove the addin from the collection of AddIns and maybe unregister.

Also, in version 2010, you might get an error of permission denied when you try to delete the file. This is caused by ppt not releasing in time the open addin file. In fact, a timer does not solve it. But a second kill will actually work.